# Prove $f(x)=\|x\|$ differentiable everywhere but in $\{0\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, normed-spaces

I have the function $f: \mathbb R ^n \to \mathbb R$ where $f(x)=\|x\|$. I have to prove that $f$ is differentiable on $E$, where $E=\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\} $, and show its derivative (for $x \ne 0 $, of course). I'm not able to split this function up in different parts, because $x$ is here a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ I assume. I do not really know how to prove differentiability in this case.

Comment: Is it $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Also are you using the standard Euclidean norm?

Comment: I corrected it. It was $\mathbb R ^n$. It's the Euclidean norm, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential is given by,

$$Df(x_1,x_2) = \left( \frac{x_1}{\|x\|}, \frac{x_2}{\|x\|} \right)$$

which has defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: This just shows that the formula that gives the differential for nonzero values is not defined at zero. How do we know that the differential is not given by a piecewise defined formula that agrees with the above when $x$ is not zero and has some specific value when $x$ is zero? For example, perhaps $Df(x_1,x_2) = \left( \frac{x_1}{\|x\|}, \frac{x_2}{\|x\|} \right)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $Df(0,0) = 42.$

Comment: In looking back over this, I see that the actual question asked is not what is suggested by the title, and **my earlier comment doesn't really apply**. The title suggests that in addition to showing differentiability for nonzero $x,$ we also want to show non-differentiability for $x=0.$ However, the actual statement of the OP's question does not ask us to prove anything for the case when $x=0.$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to get this derivative :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint valid for any inner product space: the norm is a composition of functions:
$$x\longmapsto(x,x)\longmapsto\langle x,x\rangle\longmapsto\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle} = \|x\|$$
and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is bilinear.